# Record video with a realtime timestamp watermark in IOS preferably using appcelerator

Tags: ios, video, overlay, appcelerator, recording

We are trying to do a Video recording on IOS with a Overlay of GPS Co ordinates shown in the top right corner.

We can capture video fine on Appcelerator. But not having much luck with getting the overlay in the recording.

We'd like to do this realtime rather than in post processing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, This is not something you can do using Appcelerator's video recorder. Your best bet is to write a module in native code that handles the recording and realtime overlay.